# Colocar três cores no linear-gradiente

Tags: css

Como faço para colocar três cores no linear-gradiente de forma que fique em tamanhos específico.
Por exemplo uma pokébola em cima vermelho,em baixo branco e uma linha preta ao meio

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer esse tipo de efeito com gradiente. Você deve atribuir a cada cor uma posição dentro no container na qual aquela cor passará a fazer efeito (px,%). Em seguida você define a posição final na qual a o área de atuação da mesma cor deve terminar.

Para preencher o container com uma outra cor você deve repetir o processo anterior definindo um posições de inicio e fim para atuação das novas cores.
Para que a transição entre as cores sejam imperceptível, a posição inicial das cores seguinte deve ser imediatamente seguinte a posição final da cor anterior, use bem as casas decimais (ex 30.99%,31.00%).

```
<div class='pokebola-1'>div-1<div/>
<div class='pokebola-2'>div-2<div/>
```

```
.pokebola-1{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,white 0.0, white 40.99%, black 41%, black 59.99%, red 60%, red 100%)
}

.pokebola-2{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,blue 0px, blue 40.9px, black 41px, black 59.9px, white 61.9px,white 70px)
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).